# Registering MouseDown and MouseMove on Form

Tags: c#

How and where can I register a mouse event on a form.  When I doubleclick on the form it'll generate the Form_Load event for me and I can add code into there.  However when I add something like

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e{

Console.WriteLine("mouse down")

}
```

However when I do a mousedown event on the form I don't get anything on the console.  I know something is missing where I register the event to the form or something of the sort.  Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the designer view, select the form and then in the properties window, click the little lightning bolt (events).

Here you're able to select which delegate method is called for which event. If you haven't created the method already, just double click the empty space next to an event and it will generate the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS.net then you should find all the events in the property panel. Just pick the ones you want.

If you want to grammatically register an event then the code would looks like:

```
Form1.Click += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseDown);
```

in order to unregister it's

```
Form1.Click -= new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseDown);
```

Answer (score 1):

The event needs to be "wired up" either from the designer or from code.  You can wire up an event from Visual Studio by double-clicking the event in the properties window:

[image]

Which generates [code like the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventhandler.aspx) in the auto-generated `.designer` file:

```
theForm.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseDown);
```

You can also use the code like the above to manually wire up events in your `Form_Load` method.

Answer (score 0):

By your explanation it seems like you have registered the event properly through the designer... if you still don't see the string on the console try System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (Maybe you are looking on the wrong window)

Answer (score 0):

With WinForms, you'll want to add it via the design view in Visual Studio.

While in the design view, select your form. Then, click on the 'Events' button in the Properties panel (looks like a lightning bolt) and type in the function name under the appropriate event. You can also click on an event here to automatically generate a new function in the code-behind.

As you noticed, double-clicking the form will automatically generate a certain function in the code-behind. For forms, it is Load but for other things it may be MouseDown or some other event.